# Seam and Spring

Tags: spring, seam2

does anyone know any good site which talks about Spring 3 and Seam 2 integration. I am really struggling to find something on this on the net. we are thinking about moving to spring 3 from EJB 3. i will really appreciate any good site suggestion. also a humble request to you is to keep the discussion on the topic.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The Seam manual is a good place to start: http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.2.Final/reference/en-US/html/spring.html

Comment: its a bad document which only talks about integrating seam with spring using lots of xml